# Ordered grouping without Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I am grouping train trips according to the coal mines they service, and then dealing with the each group starting with the most populous.

```
List<List<Trip>> tripsByMine = trips.GroupBy(x => x.demand.Mine)
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList())
                                    .Values.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                                    .ToList();
```

It seems to me that the `ToDictionary` call is superfluous because I just want the `Values`. Is there a shorter way of getting the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
List<List<Trip>> tripsByMine2 = trips.GroupBy(x => x.demand.Mine)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
    List<List<Trip>> tripsByMine = trips.GroupBy(x => x.demand.Mine)
                                        .Select(x => new {Key=x.Key, Values=x,Count=x.Count()})
                                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
.Select(x=>x.Values.ToList())
                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. Your result is `List<anonymous type>` not `List<List<Trip>>`

Comment: Also you're calling `ToList` twice without no apparent reason.